# Сохранение сцены в Unity в JSON + загрузка

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, десериализация

Необходимо сохранить сцену со всеми расставленными на ней объектами, включая всю информацию о них, в файл формата JSON. У каждого объекта на сцене есть префаб.

Каждый такой json-файл - это уровень. На одной из сцен у меня есть список уровней, где уровню в списке соответствует json-файл. Если выбрать уровень из списка и нажать кнопку "Загрузить", то должна создаться новая сцена, на которой, исходя из информации в json-файле, должны будут расставиться объекты.

Как это правильнее всего будет реализовать? Я изучал разные материалы на эту тему, но нашел только информацию о том, как сохранять/загружать информацию только о конкретном объекте, а не всей сцены в целом.

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться, почему нужно всё сохранить именно в json? Почему файл сцены вам не подходит?

Comment: Сохраняйте данные по этапно) Как Вы и находили информацию сохраняйте по обьектам, в одном JSON используя специальный массив, предполагая какой обьем данных вы хотите сохранить, это может вызвать много трудностей, особенно если у Вас возник вопрос по этой теме, распишите конкертно что именно вы хотите сохранить, какую информацию об обьекте?